# Read utf-8 and replace errors

Tags: go, utf-8

in python I can read a file in utf8 and replace any errors like this:

`with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as ifile:`

Is there an equivalent for golang?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn’t work? Go assumes strings are utf8 by default and will insert `\uFFFD` for invalid characters

Comment: @JimB I have not tried it. I am porting over code from python and was looking for similar functionality. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an exact match for the Python code because Go files return the file data as is.  There's no decoding step.

If your goal is fix invalid UTF-8 sequences, then use
[bytes.ToValidUTF8](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#ToValidUTF8) to fix data slurped up from the file.

```
var unicodeReplacement = []byte{0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd}

func readFileFix(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    p, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bytes.ToValidUTF8(p, unicodeReplacement), nil
}
```

Comment: Cool! thanks.
Looks like this is a close equivalent.